# How can one add breakpoints or custom code to an interface method implemented by many subclasses?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am working on source that has a lot of subclasses (call them `A` and `B`) implementing a common `interface Visitor`, with a method `visitProgram`. Is there any way to break when any of the subclasses hits this method (i.e. `A.visitProgram` or `B.visitProgram`)? Alternate language solutions would be fine, but I cannot rewrite the existing source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're debugging I assume you can add some new code and build the whole thing.

That said, you can use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to get a pointcut that captures the execution of visitProgram, and in theory you can put your breakpoint in the pointcut. You can think of AOP as a technique to cut laterally through your program (as opposed to OOP which builds "vertical" structure).

In this instance, you want to perform something just before each time `visitProgram` (of any instantiation of your `Visitor` interface) is run. This is a *lateral* cut, so AOP should fit your need.

Basically, you'll have a function in which you can set a breakpoint such that any time `visitProgram` gets called your program will halt just before it executes.

I'd recommend using [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html), it's pretty straight forward, just follow the manual for setup instructions. Your pointcut should look like this:

```
@Aspect
public class BeforeVisitProgram {

    @Before("visitProgram()")
    public void doStuff() {
      // break in here
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you use Spring AOP on objects not managed by the Spring IoC container? If not there is always [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Comment: @Gary: I'm unsure, but you should be able to tell Spring AOP what packages to look in to construct the pointcuts. I'm unfamiliar with constructing an AspectJ pointcut (for the benefit of the OP: the core concept is the same regardless of the AOP framework used).

Answer (score 3):

Use an abstract class between the calling code and your implementations, such as:

```
interface DoesStuff {
    void doStuff();
}

abstract class AbstractDoesStuff implements DoesStuff {
    void doStuff() {
        doStuffToo(); // debug point
    }

    abstract void doStuffToo();        
}
```

It does mean though that all your implementation must be subclasses of the abstract class, so this approach might not suit every situation.

Comment: Thanks, though this was more refactoring than I wanted. I have been writing any new classes in this style. (also, doStuff should be final). cheers